# D3.js graph does not appear when source is saved in file

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

HTML newbie question

I'm trying to draw a graph using D3.js

The example I'm trying to learn from can be found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/7452541/)

I tried saving the source code to a file and opening the file in chrome and IE, however the chart was not displayed. In fact the entire page is blank.

The source code is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.chart rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.chart text {
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

</style>
<svg class="chart"></svg>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  var barWidth = width / data.length;

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)"; });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", barWidth - 1);

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value) + 3; })
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
});

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value; // coerce to number
  return d;
}

</script>
```

It looks like the only included script is `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>`
so I don't think I am missing any scripts.

Comment: Did you download the data.tsv file as well?

Comment: Yep I've got that in the same directory. Probably should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to just open the .html file in your browser and have the script work, you need to serve it through an HTTP server. Python's built-in SimpleHTTPServer is a good choice. Just `cd` to the directory with your HTML file in the terminal and type `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. You should now be able to view it by opening your browser to the IP address and port listed in the terminal.

Comment: yep, was about to say it :-)